# When running scrapy spider with defined USER_AGENTS scraped items stop at 1000 counts

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to run a scrapy spider with rotated proxy list AND user agents. The output should be 1500 item_scraped_counts. When I run it **only** with proxy list then I will receive the full (1500) outputs. But when I want to run it with proxy-list **and** user_agents then it always stops at 1000 item_scraped_counts. 
I have the following activated settings:

```
BOT_NAME = 'trendanalyse_scrapy'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['trendanalyse_scrapy.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'trendanalyse_scrapy.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
PROXY_POOL_ENABLED = True
PROXY_POOL_FILTER_ANONYMOUS = True
PROXY_POOL_FORCE_REFRESH = True
PROXY_POOL_PAGE_RETRY_TIMES = 40

# library: scrapy_proxy_pool
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.ProxyPoolMiddleware': 510,
    'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 520,
}

# library scrapy_useragents
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
'scrapy_useragents.downloadermiddlewares.useragents.UserAgentsMiddleware': 400,
}

USER_AGENTS = [
('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
'Chrome/57.0.2987.110 '
'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
'Chrome/61.0.3163.79 '
'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) '
'Gecko/20100101 '
'Firefox/55.0'),  # firefox
('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
'Chrome/61.0.3163.91 '
'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
'Chrome/62.0.3202.89 '
'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
'Chrome/63.0.3239.108 '
'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
]
```

I have also tried different packages and also rotate the 'relevance' --> first proxy list with (410 and 420) and after that useragent with (500).

Comment: Is this really what your settings are? Note that you set `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` twice. This will just overwrite the first setting...

Comment: YES...I thought I had to. I adjust it and it worked fine. Great thank you for the hint.